# Cut everything from specific char (or after) + Bash

Tags: bash

I have files which all look like this:
filename.bla_1

of cours I cannot know if the filename has "_" in it. could be file_name.bla_1.
I want to write a function that take filename and delete the _# at the end.
filename.bla_1 will be --> filename.bla

```
echo $filename | rev | cut -d "_" -f2 | rev
```

will do the trick if the file doesn't have "*" in the name but I want to make sure this works also for filenames with "*"

Comment: How about simply using `'` instead of `"` for your delimeter string?`echo $filename | rev | cut -d '_' -f2 | rev` seems to do the job for me, with filenames containing both `"` and `'`.

Comment: @mijiturka why not post that as an answer instead of comment since it solves the OP's question?

Comment: @pitprok Just because it's a small change to OP's code, and choroba's (better) answer was already there when I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion. The `%` removes the shortest possible pattern on the right side of the value, `##` removes the longest possible match on the left:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for f in filename.bla_1 \
         file_name_with_underscores.foo_2 \
         file_name_with_underscores.foo \
         filename.with_dots.foo_2 ; do
    ext=${f##*.}
    basename=${f%.*}
    echo "$basename.${ext%_*}"
done
```

Comment: If a file with the name "file_name_with_underscores.foo" is passed through this, it will end up as "file_name_with". This needs editing so the _ part will only be deleted if it's found after the extension.

Comment: @pitprok: Updated to handle such filenames, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you care to tweak the globbing parser a little,

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in abc.bla a_b_c_.bla abc.bla_1 a_b_c_.bla_2 123.456.789 123.456.789_x abc_ 
do echo ${f%_+([^._])}
done
abc.bla
a_b_c_.bla
abc.bla
a_b_c_.bla
123.456.789
123.456.789
abc_
```

`${f%_+([^._])}` means the value of `$f` with a `_` followed immediately by one or more *non*-`dot-or-underscore` characters trimmed OFF the end.

Comment: c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use @choroba's answer.

But to fix your code, after you reverse the filename, you need to take *the 2nd and all following fields*, not just the 2nd:

```sh
$ filename=foo_bar_baz.bla_1
$ rev <<<"$filename" | cut -d_ -f2- | rev
foo_bar_baz.bla
```

The `-f2-` with the trailing hyphen is the magic here. Read the `cut` man page.